# Json.NET serializing float/double with minimal decimal places, i.e. no redundant ".0"?

Tags: .net, json, floating-point, json.net

When serializing floats and doubles, Json.NET always adds ".0" at the end if the number doesn't contain any fractional part. I was wondering if there was an easy way to bypass this, to result in a more compact representation? The extra periods and zeroes add up when serializing an object containing many numbers.

For example, when running this code:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(1.0);
```

I would expect (and want) this result:

```
"1"
```

But instead I get:

```
"1.0"
```

I looked at the source code and noticed that it was purposely added in commit [0319263](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/0319263756212f4a1875cda6534b9b8e1fb53188) (*"...-Fixed JsonConvert to always write a floating point number with a decimal place..."*) where it runs code that looks basically like:

```
    private static string EnsureDecimalPlace(double value, string text)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(value) || double.IsInfinity(value) ||
            text.IndexOf('.') != -1 || text.IndexOf('E') != -1 ||
            text.IndexOf('e') != -1)
        {
            return text;
        }

        return text + ".0";
    }
```

Consequently, I am wondering:

1. What may have been the reason for that change? The [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) does not seem to require it.
2. Is there an easy way to bypass it?

Comment: Newtonsoft has confirmed that this is by design, see [Decimal with no decimal point serialized as a Decimal with a decimal point #590](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/590).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **1. What may have been the reason for that change?**

The specs do not require it, but it also does not disallow it.

My guess is that it allows for better type checking for Json.NET (if they have it somewhere) or it's a "just-in-case" thing that allows differentiation between integer and floating point types.

[image: from Json.org]

> **2. Is there an easy way to bypass it?**

Not that easy, but if you really want it, you can recompile your own version of Json.NET after changing `EnsureDecimalPlace()` to simply `return text;`

Comment: Where did you get this flow diagram? Is it part of the spec? It seems to indicate that '000' is not a number.

Comment: Flow diagram is an earlier version of the one shown here: https://www.json.org/json-en.html.  Indeed numbers with leading zeros are disallowed by the JSON standard.

Answer (score 40):

As an alternative answer to question 2 (assuming you don't want to go through the hassle of compiling your own custom version of the Json.NET source) you can create your own custom JsonConverter class to handle decimal, float, and double values.  Here's the version I'm using:

```cs
    class DecimalJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public DecimalJsonConverter()
        {
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return (objectType == typeof(decimal) || objectType == typeof(float) || objectType == typeof(double));
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (DecimalJsonConverter.IsWholeValue(value))
            {
                writer.WriteRawValue(JsonConvert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(value)));
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteRawValue(JsonConvert.ToString(value));
            }
        }

        private static bool IsWholeValue(object value)
        {
            if (value is decimal decimalValue)
            {
                int precision = (Decimal.GetBits(decimalValue)[3] >> 16) & 0x000000FF;
                return precision == 0;
            }
            else if (value is float floatValue)
            {
                return floatValue == Math.Truncate(floatValue);
            }
            else if (value is double doubleValue)
            {
                return doubleValue == Math.Truncate(doubleValue);
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

This will preserve the precision on values of type decimal.  If you would prefer to ignore the precision of decimal values, you can make the decimal portion of the IsWholeValue() function work the same as the float/double portion:

```cs
        private static bool IsWholeValue(object value)
        {
            if (value is decimal decimalValue)
            {
                return decimalValue == Math.Truncate(decimalValue);
            }
            else if (value is float floatValue)
            {
                return floatValue == Math.Truncate(floatValue);
            }
            else if (value is double doubleValue)
            {
                return doubleValue == Math.Truncate(doubleValue);
            }

            return false;
        }
```

In either case, to use the above code, just call the serializer like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, new DecimalJsonConverter())
```

Comment: This method was failing for me: `CanConvert` kept returning false meaning the custom converter was not working -- until I paid close attention to the types and realised that I was serializing nullable types.  As soon as I added checks for `decimal?`, `float?` and `double?` it all started working.  Thanks!

Comment: While this answer is excellent for the most part, I'd like to warn you about the Convert.ToInt64 .. It will overflow if you try Convert.ToInt64(double.MaxValue) and crash.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8XbCir

Comment: If you have float, you will have exception in `IsWholeValue()`: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Single' to type 'System.Double'`. .NET 6

Comment: You need to have "this same" IF statement, but for float (`float floatValue = (float)value`)

Comment: @Saibamen, wow you're right.  I just assumed that since you can implicitly convert a float to a double that casting it to a double would work too, but I guess it doesn't.   Fixed.