# Preserve remove trailing zeros in Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have problem with Newtonsoft.JsonConverter in my C# app.
I have decimal with trailing zeros.
After convert to json - there zeros are missing.

**Example:**

```
input (decimal): 1.99000
output (json): 1.99
```

I have my own converter, that handles decimal value.
Also, I configured FloatParseHandling as decimal.

What can I do to preserve this process?

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is ignore the decimal property during serialization (JsonIgnore attribute) and add a new readonly string one where you  handle the format.Is this an option for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json.NET serializing float/double with minimal decimal places, i.e. no redundant ".0"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153381/json-net-serializing-float-double-with-minimal-decimal-places-i-e-no-redundant)

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug introduced in Json.NET 10.0.1 and reported [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1367). It has since been fixed in 11.0.1.

Comment: what if i want the trailing zeros to go missing?!?

Comment: @Leonardo this is another question. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49924144/1248177)