# How to remove trailing zeros during deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

so, this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684557/preserve-remove-trailing-zeros-in-newtonsoft-json?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) states that removing trailing zeros is a bug... but what if I want that behavior? Is there a way to set this?

```
input (decimal): 1.99000
```

should be

```
output (json): 1.99
```

Comment: use the version with the bug, and don't upgrade??

Comment: not an option... anyone could upgrade this and simply forget to check the serialization of a handful of edge cases

Comment: this is a real throw in the air and hope idea, but can you do a setter that takes string and a getter that produces a decimal and drop trailing 0s as part of a string?

Comment: @Leonardo I updated the post which yours is near enough to be a duplicate, with an alternative answer. Hope one or the other will help you.

Comment: @Leonardo isn't that what documentation of your project, and team knowledge, is for? I agree it's a risk, it's probably a lot easier than implementing / overriding a serialiser yourself - unless the scenario mentioned in the duplicate works for you.