# Prevent NewtonSoft Json from adding trailing 0

Tags: c#, json.net

I am facing an unexpected problem with the `NewtonSoft.Json` library. It appears it adds a trailing 0 to decimal values that do not have a decimal part:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(1m)
```

Will return the following string: `"1.0"`.

While it is not an issue in many cases, in my case, I do care about the precision the users are providing. If a user enters `1`, I need to store `1` in my database. If he provides `1.0` then I need to store `1.0`.

I am using the last version of the library: `12.0.3`, but I tried with all the previous major versions down to `9.0.1`, and they all produces the same result.

I have seen several questions about the library removing trailing 0 (reported as a bug, fixed in version 11.X), but none about adding one.

Is this a bug I should report?
How can I override this default behavior?

Comment: it's not a bug, it's a feature, if you want a different behavior than the expected one, you need to write a `TypeConverter`, but i don't wanna go into the depths of decimals

Comment: It's likely the string is `1.0` not `"1.0"`. if it's `1.0` then it's just a number and the addition of a trailing zero will make no difference to the way the JSON would be deserialised.

Comment: Why do you say this is a problem? What issues does it cause you?

Comment: @PatrickBeynio : well it's an unexpected feature from my point of view. Why is the library adding more precision to the field than it has initially?

Comment: @DavidG correct, I will edit my question for more details

Comment: Then don't you just want to store your values as a string then?

Comment: @phuzi it does not make a difference at deserialization time, but it can make a difference later. My business actually do a difference between `1.0` and `1`

Comment: Seems you need to use a string `JsonConvert.SerializeObject("1")`

Comment: @DavidG well I could but the decimal type is a perfect fit for my business case. I will dig into the solution proposed by Patrick Beynio, a custom TypeConverter

Comment: Your question sounds like a duplicate of [Json.NET serializing float/double with minimal decimal places, i.e. no redundant “.0”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21153381/10263); would you agree?

Comment: You ask *"Why is the library adding more precision to the field?"*.  It's not the library, it's Javascript (upon which JSON is based).  C# has multiple numeric types (int, float, double, decimal).  Javascript has one: *number*.  A Javascript number can represent either an integer or a number that includes decimal places; it doesn't care.  In Javascript, the expression `("1.0" == 1)` will actually evaluate to `true` (Javascript can be infuriatingly forgiving).

Comment: @Flydog57: I am not using Javascript at any point in my stack: C# to C# through a SignalR Core endpoint. There is no Javascript involved in my issue.

Comment: @Flydog57 'infuriatingly forgiving' is the most positive description of how JS checks for equality :D

Comment: Ah, but you are using JSON.  JSON is an acronym for "Javascript Object Notation".  You are using Javascript if you are using JSON - sorry.

Comment: This is by design, see [Decimal with no decimal point serialized as a Decimal with a decimal point #590](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/590).  I believe Newtonsoft does this because, in the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org), JSON literals with no digits after the decimal point (e.g. `1.`) are malformed, so `1.0` is chosen instead of `1` to hint that the value is a decimal/double not an integer.  A custom converter, as mentioned in comments above and the answer below, can override this design decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a bug, it's how the library works. If you want to override this behaviour, you will need a custom type converter, for example:

```
public class DecimalJsonConverter : JsonConverter<decimal>
{
    public override decimal ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        decimal existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, 
        decimal value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Customise how you want the decimal value to be output in here
        // for example, you may want to consider culture
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

And now serialise like this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new[] { new DecimalJsonConverter() }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(1m, settings);
```

Comment: And if the customization you want is "remove redundant trailing zeroes", then you can use e.g. `writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString($"0.{new string('#', value.Scale)}");`