# .NET Core Newtonsoft JSON - Serialize decimal without trailing zeros

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, json.net

How to remove trailing zeros while serialization in Newtonsoft.Json?

.NET Core 3.1

Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3

Global options:

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    // Response as PascalCase instead of default camelCase
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
})
```

Input is just default DTO (`MyDecimalProperty` is just decimal):

```
var data = new MyDTO();
```

Output from `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)`:

`"MyDecimalProperty":0.0`

**Expected output:**

`"MyDecimalProperty":0`

Comment: This is by design, see [Decimal with no decimal point serialized as a Decimal with a decimal point #590](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/590). I believe Newtonsoft does this because, in the JSON spec, JSON literals with no digits after the decimal point (e.g. 1.) are malformed, so 1.0 is chosen instead of 1 to hint that the value is a decimal/double not an integer.

Comment: A custom converter as given in the following questions can override this decision: [Json.NET serializing float/double with minimal decimal places, i.e. no redundant “.0”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21153381/3744182) and [Prevent NewtonSoft Json from adding trailing 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65093530/3744182).  in fact I would say this is a duplicate, agree?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was wondering why my `DecimalFormatConverter : JsonConverter<decimal>` not working